# Add text to mui datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can one add extra text to mui datepicker.
[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DateTimePicker, KeyboardDateTimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function InlineDateTimePickerDemo(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));

  return (
    <>
      <DateTimePicker
        variant="inline"
        label="Input Label"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default InlineDateTimePickerDemo;
```

The sample code above displays the image without ***'Extra Text'***

Comment: Please edit your question with actual code you are attempting, where your challenge with it lies and how we may best assist you.  Pictures while potentially useful are not enough since the smallest actual code that reproduces your issue is needed.  Please also clearly state where you have a challenge with that actual code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DateTimePicker, ToolbarComponentDefault } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function InlineDateTimePickerDemo(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));

  return (
    <>
      <DateTimePicker
        variant="inline"
        label="Input Label"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        ToolbarComponent={customToolbarReplaced}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const customToolbarReplaced = (props) => {
  return <div>Default Toolbar Replaced</div>
}

const customToolbarExtended = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ToolbarComponentDefault {...props} />
      <span>Default Toolbar Extended</span>
    </div>
  )
}


export default InlineDateTimePickerDemo;
```

To answer the question, one would have to use the prop **ToolbarComponent** as described in the [doc](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker).

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML and classes in your function for example here in my sub function part I add a box with text "Howdy Before" before the date picker and "Howdy" after:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DesktopDatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';

export default function CustomInput() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="Custom input"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={({ inputRef, inputProps, InputProps }) => (
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems:'center' }}>
            <div style={{marginRight:1 + 'rem'}}>{ 'Howdy Before' }</div>
            <input ref={inputRef} {...inputProps} />
            {InputProps?.endAdornment}
            <span style={{marginLeft:1 + 'rem',color:'#44DDDD'}}>{ 'Howdy' }</span>
          </Box>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I don't want the custom text in input field, rather in the rendered calendar. I have added the solution to this below.