# Add Label to MUI calendarpicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

Is there  a way to add a day name to each date number like this but instead of day 2 I want it to be `Tue 2` `Fri 3` and so on
[image]

Comment: You may find an answer on a similar post [here]. [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70261085/add-text-to-mui-datepicker/

Comment: This is different i want the label to be with the day itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution with scss to add day Name or any label before the day itself

[image]

[image]